# Image syncing in my server through gallery while taking photo using cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am making an app using [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) cordova, where image will sync automatically in my server as soon user clicks photo from their camera. I am not experienced in writing native android, hence I am looking for a cordova plugin which can be integrated in my ionic app. If there is no plugin, can someone please give me direction on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need are:

- Cordova Camera plugin (this can be used to take pictures or select
  from the device gallery).
- Cordova File transfer plugin (used for file
     uploads and download)

See a full code sample here https://gist.github.com/Whebcraft/befb0d757622d405808854745c3cd6a1